# How to prevent type widening for T or Promise<T>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to write a function which may take a callback or async version of it.

Something like this:

```typescript
// this is regular version it take SYNC function as callback
type Cb = <Res extends string>(cb: () => Res) => Res

const a: Cb = {} as any;

// it works with NO type widening type of t1 is "1"
const t1 = a(() => {
  return '1';
});
```

Here the same function, but it works with async callback:

```typescript
type Cb2 = <Res extends string>(cb: () => Promise<Res>) => Promise<Res>

const b: Cb2 = {} as any;

// also no type widening, type of t2 is Promise<"1">
const t2 = b(async () => {
  return '1';
});
```

But now I want to create general version of the function, which may take sync or async callback:

```typescript
type Cb3 = <Res extends string | Promise<string>>(cb: () => Res) => Res

const c: Cb3 = {} as any;

// this don't widen the type, type of t31 is "1"
const t31 = c(() => {
  return '1';
});

// but here is the problem, type of t32 is Promise<string>
const t32 = c(async () => {
  return '1';
});
```

Is it possible to write generic function which take sync or async callback and return "1" or Promise<"1">?

Comment: It will not work because if you remove `Res extends string` it will always widen type to `string`

Comment: Meanwhile there is no solution this problem [accepted for discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45338) by Typescript team.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to define a custom type `PromiseMaybe`

```
type PromiseMaybe<T> = T | Promise<T>

type Cb = <Res extends string>(cb: () => PromiseMaybe<Res>) => Res

const c: Cb = {} as any

const t31 = c(() => {
  return '1'
})

const t32 = c(async () => {
  return '1'
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work, [pls take a look](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOECyBDEAjCAHgBUA+KAXimKgB9ZFUMTSAoV0SKAYT0qkIAlCGigQAHsAgA7ACai0wOCmkBzUgAoAxngBcUDQEpK5eMnRZcBISNLGK5YWnZaE0xVC37e-AN4BfKGxRbGkQFzcPYABmAEZ+LQ0jEyhfVigoOAhgAFc4aSgAcljC1n9DdgB6SqhOCAQAM1rogCYodChFZTUAGig8HOAoaQQhgCJYsdZXdyGYtqpE4JBpLQN7cjSMrNz8opKywyA).

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Cb3 =
    /**
     * Try to change the order of these
     */
    & (<Sync extends string, Cb extends () => Sync>(cb: Cb) => ReturnType<Cb>)
    & (<Sync extends string, Cb extends () => Promise<Sync>>(cb: Cb) => ReturnType<Cb>)

declare var a: Cb3

const result = a(() => '1') // 1
const result2 = a(async () => '1') // string

/**
 * Vice versa
 */

/** Second */   function c<Sync extends string, Return extends Promise<Sync>, Cb extends () => Promise<Sync>>(cb: Cb): ReturnType<Cb>
/** First */    function c<Sync extends string, Cb extends () => Sync>(cb: Cb): ReturnType<Cb>

function c<Sync extends string, Cb extends (() => Sync) | (() => Promise<Sync>)>(cb: Cb): ReturnType<Cb> {
    return null as any

}

const t31 = c(() => '1') // string

const t32 = c(async () => '1'); // '1'
```

As you might have noticed I was able to infer only one of two cases.
Try to change the order of function overloads. You will see that every time you are able to infer literal type only from one function but not from both.

I hope somebody will come up with some better idea

While you are waiting for the answer, you can read  my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) about function arguments infering.

Comment: This is not working, because as you said it only works for one of the case. Solving one case will break the other.

Comment: This is what I have written. As I said, maybe it will help somebody to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple workaround

Use Typescript's built-in feature of [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which is designed to prevent type widening of literal types such as strings.

```
// t32 is Promise<"1">
const t32 = c(async () => {
  return '1' as const;
});
```